# Efficient way to drop dates Jupyter notebook

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, logical-operators

I have the next code:

```
Date = df_new[['Date']].groupby(['Date']).sum().reset_index()
for z in Date['Date']:
    df_old=df_old[df_old.Date != z ]
df_old
```

but it takes too long if Im trying to replace full years

is there a more efficient way to compare with a whole column?

i also tried outer merge and replace but think my full code struggles with 0s, i rather prefer droping based on a list

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to remove the dates in `df_old` that appear in `df_new`, you could just do a direct comparison using `pd.isin` to find the overlap and then negate it using `~`, to create an index to filter. This is much more efficient than using a `for` loop:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

old_dates = pd.date_range(start='01/01/2018', end='1/08/2018', freq="30min")
new_dates = pd.date_range(start='01/05/2018', end='1/06/2018', freq="30min")

# Old date values not appearing in new
diff_index = ~old_dates.isin(new_dates)

old_dates[diff_index]
```